# Maximum possible variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, applications

From this [biology article](http://darwin.eeb.uconn.edu/eeb348/lecturenotes/wahlund.pdf), end of page 4, the author talks about a random variable which never takes value outside the range $[0,1]$ ($0$ and $1$ included in the range). He says that the maximum variance that this random variable can take equals to the product expected value of the random variable by the expected value of one minus the random variable. In other words:

$$\max\mathrm{Var}\left(X\right) = \mathrm{E}(X) \cdot \mathrm{E}(1-X)$$

Is it true? Why is it true?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is true. A simple reason is that $$\mathrm{var}(X)=E(X^2)-m^2$$ where $m=E(X)$ and that, if $X$ is almost surely in $[0,1]$, then $X^2\leqslant X$ almost surely hence $E(X^2)\leqslant E(X)=m$, thus $$\mathrm{var}(X)\leqslant m-m^2=m(1-m).
$$
More generally, if $0\leqslant X\leqslant x$ almost surely then $\mathrm{var}(X)\leqslant xm-m^2$.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot! Why do you say "almost surely" while it is sure the way my variable is defined that the probability to take any value outside of the range [0,1] is zero?

Comment: Then "almost surely" holds, doesn't it?

Comment: Ha ha Ok! Thanks

Comment: I want to ask, if we don't know that $E(X)=m$, then is the maximum of the $Var(X)= x^2/4$? i.e. by letting $m = X/2$?

Comment: @fizis ?? We *defined $m$ as $m=E(X)$.

Comment: I mean, if the question changed: given $X$ is the random variables in the range of $[0,x]$, what is the maximum variance allowed for $X$? That is, you are not told about what $E(x)$ is, you are free to assume the distribution of random variables $X$.

Comment: If this is a harder question, I may open a new post, if it is trivial, I think I will just hear what you think.

Comment: @fizis Not harder, actually the answer is already in my post... The maximum value of $xm-m^2$ when $m$ varies is at $m=\frac12x$, where the value is $\frac14x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

as an illustration consider a distribution in which x takes value 1 with probability m and value 0 with probability 1-m. then the expected value is m and the variance is m-m^2 = m*(1-m)

Answer (score 0):

That is the variance of a Bernoulli random variable, which is confined to take only the values 1 or 0. If you hold the expected value constant then concentrating the probability at the extreme values of the variable will make it more variable than letting it take values that can be closer together